# assert type from property

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a CARD type, which can be either a TEXT_CARD or an IMAGE_CARD:

```js
declare type TEXT_CARD = {
  type: "paragraph" | "h1" | "h2";
  text: string;
};

declare type IMAGE_CARD = {
  type: "img";
  src: string;
  orientation: "portrait" | "landscape";
};

declare type CARD = TEXT_CARD | IMAGE_CARD;
```

When rendering a card, I want to switch between these two to render separate components.

```html
<!-- index.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  import TextCard from "./TextCard.svelte";
  import ImageCard from "./ImageCard.svelte";
  export let card: CARD;
</script>

{#if ["paragraph", "h1", "h2"].includes(card.type)}
  <TextCard {card} />
{:else}
  <ImageCard {card} />
{/if}



<!-- TextCard.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  export let card: TEXT_CARD;
</script>

<h1>{card.text}</h1>



<!-- TextCard.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  export let card: IMAGE_CARD;
</script>

<h1>{card.src}</h1>
```

But now, in index.svelte, typescript complains that CARD is not assignable to TEXT_CARD.

`Type 'CARD' is not assignable to type 'TEXT_CARD'.`

How and where do I assert that I'm sure I'm dealing with a TEXT_CARD / IMAGE_CARD? Or should I set up my types differently to start with?

Comment: It will work if you'll swap the if/else: `if (card.type === 'img') ...` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgUQBpwPpwJoAUEGUYC8MA2gEQAOAhgE6UDmt5AFqQDQylMCMbHTATKQC6MShBihIUANwBYAFAKoAT3IBTeMjQBhAIIAlACKEYAbwUwYK9QC4rqtSABmmlOmx5iYAK4BbAEZq1EJy8pZQagAeUHbQ1ACWYHShAL6hSg4wAJIAsroA4gioekYm5mH2thzxvnSkoZYQ1MCxUAlJDTAgCWpgUJRQ8eB2FN1tlPFQpDAAPhwANpRgACYQwJTq9QppChnqMCXGRIhuh7PZeYXFBobp8k7eYMCD4DBOICAAFOvUy3aHAEozBYYPEXN8aMsAHTWDQEeEwADkNToiIBIMsWV89DU2khEN+6IqanmEDUGPgUSgeN+BOWRJSu3kyzUwEW1A0DyeLzAlOiNOWdLsJx0NwBdiWygULLZNE5j2eQ15WJxAqFFwKRUBErAyiAA

Comment: Thanks Aleksey L. I would still like it to have a general solution that would work if more types get added to the CARD type. But this does work fine for now :)

Comment: You can go with `switch` then (if svetle allows this) https://tsplay.dev/w6BMew

Comment: Yea, I was searching for this in inline Svelte html. Doesnt look like it is supported, which makes this question a weird combination between a typescript question and a Svelte (Sveltekit) question :). Anyway, thanks for the suggestions and for now my code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I will encourage you to define `["paragraph", "h1", "h2"]` in a constant. You can then easily tell TypeScript the right type like:

```js
const CUSTOM_TYPES: CARD['type'][] = ["paragraph", "h1", "h2"]
```

TypeScript won't complain anymore if you use it like the following:

```js
{#if CUSTOM_TYPES.includes(card.type)}
  ...
{/if}
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion for better typescript, but this does not solve my problem - the ts error still exists after applying this